# why cann't i capture 3g data use wireshark and winPcap

Tags: android, wireshark, 3g-network

when I install  **Wireshark-win32-1.10.5.exe(this is a stable version)** and

**WinPcap_4_1_3.exe/3.1-WinPcap.exe(also stable version)**,

I also set all parameters in my android phone and xp os,
then i run

```
  " ./data/local/tcpdump-arm -n -s 0 -w - | nc -l -p 7100 " in phone shell console,

  run"adb forward tcp:6100 tcp:7100 && nc 127.0.0.1 6100 | wireshark -k -S -i – "
```

in xp os console, but when the wireshark started, it prompts a dialog, it says:

> The capture session could not be initiated (Error opening adapter:xxx)
>   Please check that (-) is the proper interface. Help can be found at
>   ...

Comment: You have three possible points of failure - your attempt to capture packets on the device itself (permission or option issues), the network forward, or the invocation syntax of wireshark.  The error message you are currently getting suggests problems with the latter, but you may well have problems with the capturing itself too.  You might want to try it in pieces, for example piping locally captured data into wireshark, capturing on the android device to a file and examining it, etc.

Comment: I am sure the device have root permission and all the files in the device also have 777 permission.The adb tool is usable

Comment: other more, I hope to capture packets in real time, not in pieces

Comment: The point of trying things in pieces is to identify the problem so that you can fix it, not to do it piecewise in the long run.

Comment: Please post your own solution, and then accept it after the delay, so that the question shows as resolved rather than unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following command and was able to capture traffic from emulator:

```
adb shell tcpdump -i any -p -s 0 -w /sdcard/capture.pcap
```

Then you can pull the capture file by:

```
adb pull /sdcard/capture.pcap
```

It will pull the file to the windows location from which you invoke this command.

Looks at this link for more details: http://www.kandroid.org/online-pdk/guide/tcpdump.html

Hope that helps.

Comment: Perhaps, but you are presenting an alternative which assumes a built-in tcpdump and permission on the executable or adb for it to run (neither true on current releases), rather than answering the question which was asked.